# How to determine BUCKET_COUNT for Hash Indexes for SQL Server Memory Optimized Tables

Tags: sql-server

I create an optimized table on SQL Server and

I want to check hash index of this table every month

If BUCKET_COUNT of hash index is low then determine a new one and update it

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a job with the optimal period and use this command:

```
DECLARE @NumberRecords INT
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Indexes TABLE
(
    [RowId]                 INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Table]                 NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [Index]                 NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [Columns]               NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [TOTAL_BUCKET_COUNT]    BIGINT          NOT NULL
)

INSERT @Indexes
SELECT  '[' + schema_name([Objects].[schema_id]) + '].[' + [Objects].[name] + ']',
        '[' + [Indexes].[name] + ']',
        SUBSTRING([IndexedColumns], 1, LEN([IndexedColumns]) - 1),
        [HashIndexStats].[total_bucket_count]
FROM sys.dm_db_xtp_hash_index_stats [HashIndexStats]
JOIN sys.indexes [Indexes] ON   [HashIndexStats].[object_id] = [Indexes].[object_id] AND
                                [HashIndexStats].[index_id] = [Indexes].[index_id]
JOIN sys.objects [Objects] ON   [Objects].[is_ms_shipped] != 1 AND
                                [Objects].[object_id] = [Indexes].[object_id]
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT '[' + [Columns].[name] + '], '
                FROM sys.index_columns [IndexColumns]
                JOIN sys.columns [Columns] ON   [IndexColumns].[index_id] = [Indexes].[index_id] AND
                                                [IndexColumns].[object_id] = [Columns].[object_id] AND
                                                [Objects].[object_id] = [Columns].[object_id] AND
                                                [IndexColumns].[column_id] = [Columns].[column_id]
                ORDER BY [Columns].column_id
                FOR XML PATH ('')) D ([IndexedColumns])

SET @RowCount = 1
SET @NumberRecords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Indexes)
WHILE (@RowCount <= @NumberRecords)
BEGIN

    SELECT @Command = ( 'DECLARE @BUCKET_COUNT BIGINT ' +
                        'SELECT @BUCKET_COUNT = POWER(2, CEILING(LOG(IIF(COUNT(0) > 0, COUNT(0), 1)) / LOG(2))) ' +
                        'FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ' + [Columns] + ' FROM ' + [Table] + ') T ' +
                        'IF (@BUCKET_COUNT != ' + CAST([TOTAL_BUCKET_COUNT] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ') ' +
                        'BEGIN ' +
                        'EXEC(''ALTER TABLE ' + [Table] + ' ALTER INDEX ' + [Index] + ' REBUILD WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = '' + @BUCKET_COUNT + '' )'') ' +
                        'END')
    FROM @Indexes
    WHERE [RowId] = @RowCount

    EXEC(@Command)

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1

END
```